# Passing variable arguments to a delegate

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, dynamic, delegates

I have the following delegate:

```
public delegate object DynamicFunction(dynamic target, params object[] args);
```

However, when I try to create it:

```
DynamicFunction func = new DynamicFunction((t) => {
     //Handle t
});
```

The compiler throws an error saying that the delegate does not take 1 argument, even though I specified the last argument to be of type `params object[]`.

If I pass **exacly one** extra argument to the delegate, it works.
For example:

```
DynamicFunction func = new DynamicFunction((t,a) => {
     //Handle t
});
```

However, I don't want to specify that extra argument, as I intentionally wanted those arguments to be optional.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`params` mean that compiler will do smart thing when you call the function to convert whatever arguments you've passed to array.

It does not mean that function itself takes 1 or 2 parameters, and it does not mean there are 2 version of function `f(dynamic target)` and `f(dynamic target, params object[] args)`.

Note that you still want to be able to call

```
func (1);
func(1, optional1, optional2);
```

So your delegate need to handle both.

Answer (score 1):

When *invoking* the delegate the caller can provide 1...n arguments.  What you're doing now isn't invoking the delegate, but rather assigning a compatible method to a delegate of that type.  When doing so you need to provide *exactly two* arguments (of the appropriate type), because that's what the delegate's definition states it must accept.